# Installing CoreOS on a single machine

Tags: linux, bare-metal, coreos

How would I go about installing CoreOS on a single machine as the host OS?

I have read ["Installing CoreOS to Disk"](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/installing-to-disk/) and ran the `coreos-install` script from Debian and CentOS live CDs, but both seem to miss the `-p` argument for the `lsblk` command which the script needs to load config files. Even after I updated **util-linux**, it is still not working.

Is using a live CD the right approach? PXE isn't an option in my situation.

**Solution: In the end I used the latest Arch linux live cd, that worked fine.**

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/init/master/bin/coreos-install
$ sudo bash coreos-install -d /dev/sda
$ mkdir rootfs
$ mount -t btrfs -o subvol=root /dev/sda9 rootfs #sda9 is the default root partition
$ mkdir -p rootfs/var/lib/coreos-install
$ wget http://bit.ly/abcd  #the location of your cloud config file
$ mv abcd rootfs/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `-p` (alternately `--paths`) was [added](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/c7e76cd145b0c40e1d346203f3222f5937146939) in util-linux 2.24. Did you try a live system with that version?

Comment: Enterprise Linux 6 comes with util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6.i686.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me using Ubuntu Trusty livecd

```
~$ sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/init/master/bin/coreos-install
~$ sudo chmod +x coreos-install
~$ sudo ./coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C alpha -c ~/cloud-config.yaml
```

Though can you can mount the /dev/sda to do manual tweaking (rather than using/creating a cloud-config.yaml) via...

```
~$ mount -o subvol=root /dev/sda9 /mnt
```

.. like removing the root and core password, create systemd unit file for docker, etcd and fleet.

Comment: Just found out that the $public_ipv4 and $private_ipv4 in cloud-config (user_data) does not work in installing to disk. Even if reboot the system many times.