# Install CoreOS to disk via USB

Tags: installation, coreos

I want to install CoreOS to the disk of an dedicated server, from a USB stick.

In CoreOS's documentation I found the [Installing to Disk](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/installing-to-disk/) guide that requires another Linux set up and running as base. Unfortunately, I do not have that. Instead, I'm running OS X on my MacBook Pro, and I'd like to run installation of CoreOS using a USB stick.

So what I'm thinking of looks like this:

- Prepare a USB stick with CoreOS installer on MacBook Pro.
- Attach USB stick to Intel NUC and boot the machine.
- Wait until CoreOS has been installed, then remove USB stick and reboot Intel NUC.

Is there some way to get this working? If so, how do I do that? If not, what's the easiest alternative?

Comment: When I want to ask about CoreOS I look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreos-user I get an answer really fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the [CoreOS ISO](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/iso/) to USB using dd.or a similar tool.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Boot it, and run coreos-install directly by following the [Install to disk](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/installing-to-disk.html) instructions found on the CoreOS website.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have physical access to the machine (keyboard + screen), you can install CoreOS from any Linux LiveCD. You could create a [bootable Ubuntu USB on OSX](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), then boot to that, and then use the [CoreOS install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/init/master/bin/coreos-install) from the Ubuntu live boot.

Once you have logged in, it would look something like:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/init/master/bin/coreos-install
chmod +x coreos-install
./coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c cloud-config.yml
```

But the process is documented in a few places, try [here](http://stevieholdway.tumblr.com/post/90167512059/coreos-bare-metal-iso-install-tutorial) or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/592225/installing-coreos-on-a-single-machine).